# How do I add a selection icon in SAP B1 Crystal Report Parameter Field

Tags: crystal-reports, sapb1

I have created a Crystal Report that will be added in SAP B1. This has two parameter fields @ItemCodeFrom and @ItemCodeTo. The Crystal Report will pass the parameter values to a store procedure. At the moment the parameter fields are static- you need to fill the up. I would want the parameter fields to have some sort of a selection icon similar to ones in SAP B1. You click the icon and the list of items will appear for you to choose from. The parameter fields can also be enterable if the user wishes to type in directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can Choose Dynamic as the list of Values Type from the edit parameter menu
and choose the field that will populate the list from your Database fields

[image]

as far as I know there is no option to allow a Custom Value this way.

If the Data is Generally unchanging You can populate the Static List with values from the Database using the Actions Drop Down, then select append all database values.
[image]

Doing so will also allow the user to enter a custom value as well as be presented with a list.